# SAP HCI - WSDL Error - must not define an output, only one-way operations are allowed

Tags: salesforce, wsdl, sap-cpi

I am trying to integrate Salesforce with SAP HCI and for that I am using Eclipse. I am following [this guide](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/01/24/hci-integrating-salesforce-using-hci-using-rest-api/) and the WSDL I am using was generated in the Salesforce portal.

The problem is that when I deploy the integration flow, I get the following error:

> The operation defined in the WSDL must not define an output, only one-way operations are allowed

This doesn't make sense. To test this, I create my own WSDL with just input parameters and I still get the same error.

What am I not getting?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds weird, SAP HCI (now CPI) supports not only one way operations but it might be due to a setting you had in your SOAP channel (e.g. Reliable), how does your channel settings and WSDL look like?

Comment: Can't remember anymore, it was 4 months ago. I remember this was not the correct approach to the desired solution, though.